# Air travel with pet budgie

Tags: safety, birds, travel

It was suggested to me to also post this question here, originally posted here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145509/air-travel-with-pet-budgie

I was wondering if anyone has experience traveling with transatlantic (Western Europe to Mexico) with a pet bird? From what little research I did I found out that some airlines do seem to allow this, but I was more wondering about comfort for the animal and risks associated with such travel. Specifically, the birds are budgies (these ones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgerigar).

Edit: we don't currently have a budgie, but we are considering getting one. But we frequently need to travel transatlantic for extended periods (1-3 months).

Answer (score 2):

We flew with an African Grey on domestic US flights. Several years ago, the bird required a ticket (traveling in the passenger area). Also a health certificate from the vet. No problem at all, she was a hit with the attendants who brought her snacks. Are you thinking of the bird being with the cargo?  Also, I would think there could be quarantine problems going to other countries.